# Remove Chocolatey registration without uninstalling application

Tags: chocolatey

I want to be able to use `choco upgrade all -y` to update *almost* all of my Chocolatey packages.

Some packages represent applications that I want to have installed, but I no longer want them to be updated, at least not automatically by the `choco upgrade all` command.

Can I remove a package from Chocolatey without actually uninstalling the application? That would have the desired effect.

Or can I achieve my goal in a better way?

Comment: You can use pin (see `choco pin -h` for details) and Chocolatey will not try to upgrade the package. https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsPin

Comment: A new option is synchronize in pro/business - https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-synchronize

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can use pin (see [choco pin -h](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/commands/pin) for details) and Chocolatey will not try to upgrade the package: `choco pin add -n=packageName`. After that command `choco upgrade all` will skip package with name `packageName`.
2. You can remove application from Chocolatey database (you must remove application folder). All applications metadata are stored in folder `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\<package-name>`, example: `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\adobereader`.

   Remove directory carefully, because sometimes applications are installed inside chocolatey applications folder, example: `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\javadecompiler-gui\jd-gui-windows-1.4.0`

Comment: Looks like that works. And this has no ill side effects for chocolatey? No config files that need to be modified?

Comment: Chocolatey stores all packages data in `lib` folder, so you can safely remove those folders.

Comment: Option 2, I won't edit this (as it is already the accepted answer), but you can also pin the packages you don't want upgraded. It's a much better solution versus having to manually go and remove the files.

Comment: @agabrys if you want me to edit the answer I can add the details about pin. Or you can edit it.

Comment: I modified the answer. Always feel free to extends any answers ;)

Comment: You can also add the new synchronize feature as Option 3 - https://chocolatey.org/docs/features-synchronize

Comment: The question is "how to remove an application from chocolatey (registry) without uninstall it from the operating system". Synchronization is a feature which will uninstall application form chocolatey, after you uninstall it from the operating system. So I think that option does not fit into the answer :-)

Comment: I can't understand how to use the pin command. Can you edit your answer and add full command for a package?

Answer (score 66):

**Example** (remove the package `myExamplePackage` from chocolatey without uninstalling)

```
choco uninstall myExamplePackage -n --skipautouninstaller
```

From the [chocolatey docs](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-uninstall):

> NOTE: A package with a failing uninstall can be removed with the
>   `-n --skipautouninstaller` flags. This will remove the package from
>   chocolatey without attempting to uninstall the program.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the command - can you tell me the full command for a package?

Comment: sure - I added an example to the post.

Comment: This no longer seems to work with the current version of Chocolatey

Comment: works here (used it for `choco uninstall docker-desktop -n --skipautouninstaller`)

Comment: For the curious: `-n` means _Skip Powershell - Do not run chocolateyUninstall.ps1. Defaults to false._